# sencha touch cross domain form submit

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, cross-domain, form-submit

I need to know if I can make a cross domain form submit.
for example : I have a login form in a website, I want to send post request with the usermane and password to do the login process and the get the result, I don't know if this is possible with Sencha touch.
I did this once in C# application
here is the C# code to explain the idea more :

```
private void SubmitUser(object args)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = ((WebBrowser)args).Document;
        HtmlElement userName = doc.GetElementById("USER_ID");
        HtmlElement passWord = doc.GetElementById("PASSWORD");
        userName.InnerText = "training";
        passWord.InnerText = "123456";
        HtmlElement Submit = doc.GetElementById("LoginBtn");
        Submit.InvokeMember("click");
        Step = "Home";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

In short - you can do this, but it would require some changes on your server side.

Comment: I dont have access on the server side

Comment: Then read about JsonP: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP it should allow cross domain requests